# "viel zu selten" translation into English

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is "far too often" the correct equivalent for "viel zu selten"? I have already checked Google Translate and some dictionaries but feel that the meaning must be negative not positive.

Comment: What did your dictionaries suggest? How did you get *selten* as a translation for *often*? Please specify. Here we can not reproduce the translation you claim to get from Google translate.

Comment: Right before sending this post I checked Google translate Three times and then checked My Duden-Oxford dictionary. I marked the translation as 'not helpful' and sent a correction, although I don't think it has been so quick to be changed! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite the opposite.

"Far too rare" would be a correct way of expressing that, "selten" means "rare".

Comment: And rarely (adv) and seldom.